# A coin strikes the circumference of a circle from within the boundary of the circle at some random angle.

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

A coin strikes the circumference of a circle from within the boundary of the circle at some random angle theta normal to tangent at that point (where theta is a constant), and keeps moving in the same plane as if there is no friction. At which strike with circumference again (n = ?), coin repeats its trajectory/ path?
(For theta = 0, 30, 45 degrees, etc., the solution is simple. But what if theta is not among these? )

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:number-theory] or with [tag:polygons]?

Comment: If I’m reading the question correctly, theta is fixed no matter where it hits the circle. Hint: look up the tangent property of circles.

Comment: For every equilateral polygon there will be a repetitive solution. For every angel a multiple of $\pi$ there will be a closed repetitive sequence.